# Removing iCloud on an old phone

Tags: icloud

I have iCloud on more than one phone—my old iPhone 5c broke and the screen doesn't work. I now have a new phone with iCloud backed up and it works fine. I want to sell my old phone but they state that iCloud must be removed. How do I do this on icloud.com without wiping my other phone?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Connect your iPhone 5c with your PC/Mac and open iTunes
> 2. Restore the 5c to factory settings (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414)
> 3. Go to your [Apple Support Profile](https://supportprofile.apple.com) and de-register it.

That should be it.

In addition, you can [delete old iPhone Backups from the iCloud](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12792):

> 1. Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage.
> 2. Tap the name of an iOS device whose backup you don’t need, then tap Delete Backup.